# API call within a Web API fails

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web api backend.
I am trying to make a call to another web api from within one of our api controllers.

When I run this as a unit test it works fine.
However, when it is hosted on IIS Express the GetAsync call fails with the exception: "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8888".

When we host it on azure we also get a similar exception.

Is there a setting in our web.config missing?
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

looks like it is still pointing to local host, needs to point to IIS or Azure server.

Check for hardcoded values in test code or web config.